# how to compress data using php codeigniter with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am developing a system that includes a log history. In the log history is the record of actions taken by every users. Someone suggested that I have to compress the data annually because the database is expected to grow and so that I can save space. I have this table:

```
    delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `actionhistory` (
    `historyID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `empID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `item` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `actionTaken` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `dateActTaken` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`historyID`),
    KEY `emp` (`empID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=429 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

What is the syntax in doing it? I want to do it annually regardless of how many rows it has per year.

EDIT: I have read about using `ROW_FORMAT, KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` but since the row per year is not constant, I didn't use it.

Comment: what do you mean by compress???  save it in text file, zip it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take out Year (Y) form field dateActTaken to identify which year is it. Once you have year then you can fetch all records belonging to that year.

As far as compression, you can take it in zip file or you can save yearly data in your other mining databases.

Comment: what is the syntax in doing it? I mean, I can take out the year in the field and fetch it but I don't know how to zip it..

Comment: write that records in csv file http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php , http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php